# Expanding Oracle rows with comma-delimited values into multiple rows

Tags: oracle, connect-by

I have a table in Oracle like the following:

```
KEY,VALS
k1,"a,b"
```

I need it to look like:

```
KEY,VAL
k1,a
k1,b
```

I did this with `CONNECT BY` and `LEVEL`, following an [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database):

```sql
with t as (
    select 'k1' as key, 'a,b' as vals
    from dual
)
select key, regexp_substr(vals, '[^,]+', 1, level) as val
from t
connect by LEVEL <= length(vals) - length(replace(vals, ',')) + 1
```

But when I have multiple rows in the table, and the `vals` can be comma-delimited values of different lengths, like:

```
KEY,VALS
k1,"a,b"
k2,"c,d,e"
```

I'm looking for a result like:

```
KEY,VAL
k1,a
k1,b
k2,c
k2,d
k2,e
```

But the naive approach above doesn't work because [every level is connected with the one above it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541259), resulting in:

```sql
with t as (
    select 'k1' as key, 'a,b' as vals
    from dual
    union
    select 'k2' as key, 'c,d,e' as vals
    from dual
)
select key, regexp_substr(vals, '[^,]+', 1, level) as val
from t
connect by LEVEL <= length(vals) - length(replace(vals, ',')) + 1
```

```
KEY,VAL
k1,a
k1,b
k2,e
k2,d
k2,e
k2,c
k1,b
k2,e
k2,d
k2,e
```

I suspect I need some kind of [CONNECT BY PRIOR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) condition, but I'm not sure what. When trying to match by keys:

```
connect by prior key = key
       and LEVEL <= length(vals) - length(replace(vals, ',')) + 1
```

I get an `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` error.

What's the right approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Simple, fast string functions and a recursive query:

```sql
with t (key, vals) as (
    SELECT 'k1', 'a,b'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'k2', 'c,d,e' FROM DUAL
),
bounds (key, vals, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT key, vals, 1, INSTR(vals, ',', 1)
  FROM t
UNION ALL
  SELECT key, vals, epos + 1, INSTR(vals, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY key SET key_order
SELECT key,
       CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(vals, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(vals, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS val
FROM   bounds;
```

#### Option 2: Slower regular expressions in a LATERAL joined hierarchical query

This option requires Oracle 12 or later.

```sql
with t (key, vals) as (
    SELECT 'k1', 'a,b'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'k2', 'c,d,e' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT key, val
FROM   t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT regexp_substr(vals, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(vals, '[^,]+')
       )
       ON (1 = 1)
```

#### Option 3: Recursive query correlating to parent rows.

This option is the slowest of the options as it needs to correlate between levels of the hierarchy and generate a GUID at each step (which is seemingly useless but prevents unnecessary recursion).

```sql
with t (key, vals) as (
    SELECT 'k1', 'a,b'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'k2', 'c,d,e' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT key,
       regexp_substr(vals, '[^,]+', 1, level) AS val
FROM   t
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(vals, '[^,]+')
AND PRIOR key = key
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL;
```

---

Which all output:

> | KEY | VAL |
> | --- | --- |
> | k1 | a |
> | k1 | b |
> | k2 | c |
> | k2 | d |
> | k2 | e |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a8df3b4687229fd131aa15a15b74d57)*

Comment: The `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL` makes most sense to me! Thanks!